# Rich Text Editor in Rails: Show the target tab for links in the link dialog window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ckeditor, activeadmin, rich-text-editor

I am using Activeadmin with Rich Editor.
When I add a link to my text within the window of the editor i cannot set how the link is being opened - wether it is in a new tab or a new window ..

I understand that the Rich editor derives from CKEditor with certain features being disabled and that these features can be reenabled. 
Also I know, that this particular feature is set in the config by the line

```
config.linkShowTargetTab = true
```

I am just not sure on where to put it exactly so that it is enabled globally.

Thanks for any advice on this.

Comment: Which gem is Rich Editor exactly? (github link)

Comment: https://github.com/bastiaanterhorst/rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the gem source (lib/rich.rb) you can see the default buttons defined in @@editor[:toolbar]:

```
@@editor = {
...
:removeDialogTabs => 'link:advanced;link:target',
...
```

}

If I delete ";link:target" the Tab is shown in my app.